# Ruby: how to remove items from array A if it's not in array B?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have prepare these two arrays:

```
list_of_students = Student.where('class = ?', param[:given_class])
list_of_teachers = Teacher.where(...)
```

`Student` belongs_to `Teacher` and `Teacher` has_many `students`.

And now, I'd need to remove from the `list_of_students` all items (students), where `teacher_id` is not included in `list_of_teachers`.

I found some tips and HOWTO's on comparing arrays, but none of that helped to figure out this case.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `IN` SQL statement.

```
list_of_students = Student.where('class = ? AND teacher_id IN (?)', param[:given_class], list_of_teachers.map(&:id))
```

If the `list_of_teachers` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (and not an array), you can also use `#pluck(:id)` or (from Rails 4) `#ids`

```
Student.where('class = ? AND teacher_id IN (?)', param[:given_class], list_of_teachers.ids)
```

There are several ways to write the `IN` statement. Given you already have a `where`, I joined it to the main where. But you could also write

```
Student.where('class = ?', param[:given_class]).where(teacher_id: list_of_teachers)
```

or

```
Student.where(class: param[:given_class], teacher_id: list_of_teachers)
```

Also note you don't need to assign the list of teachers to a variable.

```
Student.where(class: param[:given_class], teacher_id: Teacher.where(...).ids)
```

Last but not least, if your `Teacher` query is simple, you may want to use a single query and a JOIN. Assume you want to get all the Teachers with name `Rose`.

```
Student.where(class: param[:given_class], teacher_id: Teacher.where(name: 'Rose').ids)
```

You can rewrite the same query to

```
Student.where(class: param[:given_class]).joins(:teacher).where(teacher: { name: 'Rose' })
```

or (the final and shorter expression)

```
Student.joins(:teacher).where(class: param[:given_class], teacher: { name: 'Rose' })
```

Comment: @user984621 just make sure you switch the order of your queries so `list_of_teachers` is the first one run as obviously Simone is using the result from that in his query

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,4,5]

pry(main)> a.delete_if {|a1| !b.include? a1}
=> [1]
```

it checks each value in a is in b or not. If not it deletes the value from a and gives you a array finally.

This is an example. You can use this accordingly

Comment: the question is about queries

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ,  OP says I have prepared these 2 arrays (Well they are Relations) but he is asking how to remove them from the arrays.

Comment: I think the question is not speaking about queries, Instead speaking about how to delete from 2nd array so posted my answer accordingly!